# Is downloading an object from a bucket via public url from a Google instance charged?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I would like to upload images to a bucket, and use a google VM Instance to download the image / edit it on the fly and serve it.
The outgoing traffic from the VM is already paid, do I also have to calculate the bandwidth from google cloud storage to the VM? Or being in the same network is not paid? In the documentation I found "Accessing data in an EU bucket with an EU-WEST1 GKE instance. - Free" does the same also apply to Custom VM instances?

Comment: Network bandwidth pricing is complicated in the cloud. Bandwidth is a revenue generator for cloud vendors. In some cases egress is free but the same traffic is charged for ingress (the bucket is egress but the VM is ingress) or the reverse. You will need to precisely specify everything to get a good/correct answer.

Comment: The bucket and the VM instance are in the same region, the data egress from bucket to VM, using public  url

Comment: Edit your question with those details which are not detailed enough. Then look up the pricing for each item in Google's documentation and include those details in your question. Or do the reverse, look up the pricing for each item, and then match to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

It will mostly depend on the location of your resources.

Downloading an object will necessarily imply a network egress, but since the egress will stay within Google Cloud the cost will be highly reduced (free in most cases) compared to egress costs to an external location.

Basically, the network egress cost will be cheap or free if the GCS bucket and your GCE instance are located in the same continent, and will be priced at standard rates on other cases.

You can find the pricing details on this page, in the "Network egress within Google Cloud" section which lists the various scenarios: https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing

Note that you will also need to consider the cost of the read operations when downloading the object.

Comment: The bucket and the VM instance are in the same region. I try to find the answer in the pricing without lucky

Comment: The documentation does not explicitly describe this scenario but I believe this will fall under "Data moves within the same location" category (which is free in terms of network egress), if the bucket and the instance are in the same region.

Answer (score 0):

Egress from Cloud Storage into a GCE instance in the same Cloud zone is free, networking-wise. However, you will still be charged any retrieval cost (free for Standard storage, a few cents per gigabyte for nearline, coldline, or archive) and an operation charge ($0.004 per 10,000 read operations). The ingress into a compute engine instance in the same zone is also free.

For more, check out the pricing policy for [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) and [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing). Keep in mind that this is very general advice and a lot depends on exact details here.

Comment: Thanks, the bucket and the VM instance are in the same region, I request the file from the bucket via the public link through the VM. 
If I make a curl from the vm https://storage.cloud.google.com/my_bucket/myfile.ext
so i will not be charged for the outgoing bandwidth?

Comment: Based on your description, I believe not. That said, I expect your next step would presumably be to serve that data to some customer external to the cloud, and you would be charged for that bandwidth.